# Convert String to Epoch Time

Tags: java

I have a string `startTimestamp` which is a string, and I am trying to convert it to a `epoch time` as follows.

```
Date starttimesampTime = new Date(Long.parseLong(startTimestamp));

Long epoch = starttimesampTime.getTime() / 1000;
```

[image]

However, I am getting the following exception

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2017-10-19
>   16:18:03.779"

Comment: Well yes, it's not clear why you expected `Long.parseLong` to cope with "2017-10-19 16:18:03.779". I suggest you search for the (numerous) questions of how to parse a `Date` from Java.

Comment: `Long` is a numerical type. It cannot contain the `'-', ':'`, or `' '`, that are in your input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the time, you need to go throw a `type` which can hold day/year/hour..., you need to `parse` your `String` and then get the `time` :

- with `LocalDatetime, ZonedDateTime` :

```
ZonedDateTime ldate = LocalDateTime.parse(str, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
                                   .atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
long time = ldate.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
System.out.println(time);
```

- with `Date` but it'll need to enhandle `ParseException`

```
String str = "2017-10-19 16:18:03.779";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date = df.parse(str);
long epoch = date.getTime();
System.out.println(epoch);
```

Both will print `1508422683779`

Comment: Please can you give the "UTC" version of this, not the "Paris" version.

Comment: @samthebest just replace `Europe/Paris` by `UTC`

Answer (score 4):

Since you can not convert String into Long I recommend transforming string into date then into epoch

```
String str = YOUR STRING;
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YOUR String Date PATTERN");
Date date = df.parse(str);
long epoch = date.getTime();
System.out.println(epoch);
```

Comment: Wrong pattern, take a second to look at his string

Comment: @azro sorry forgot about this bit haha took a quick example from my own code. Gonna Edit now

Comment: Starting with Java 8 there is a new date-time framework that aside from being more modern, is more sensible.  You don't want to get dinged in code reviews by using java.util.Date unless you have to.